# assertRaises and lambda expressions, Python

Tags: python, lambda, python-unittest

I know I can call `assertRaises` in a Python unit test like this:

`self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: my_fxn(bad_arg))`

If I omit the `lambda` expression, `my_fxn` is evaluated before `assertRaises`, and the `ValueError` is thrown before the `assertRaises` function is available to handle it.

What I'm not sure of, and what I think the existing answers on this topic don't do a good job of explaining, is *why* the use of `lambda` here fixes the unhanded exception problem. I know that lambda expressions are often used to pass a function to another function as an argument (or return a function from another function), but it doesn't seem like `lambda` is required in order to pass a function in as an argument. For example, I can  call `assertEquals` like without any trouble like this:

`assertEquals(my_fxn(arg1), my_result)`

So what exactly is going on here? It seems that the use of `lambda` somehow "delays" the evaluation of `my_fxn`. How does it work?

Comment: Yes, exactly. `assertRaises` has a `try/except` in it to stop the exception escaping.

Comment: A lambda expression defines a function. The code in the function isn't run until the function is executed. That's what a function is.

Comment: @khelwood I realize that. The other part of my question was why I can get away with `assertEquals(my_fxn(arg1), my_result)` (no lambda) but not `self.assertRaises(ValueError, lambda: my_fxn(bad_arg))`.

Comment: Because  `assertRaises` can't catch an exception that happens outside of it.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. But in the case of `assertEquals` it's fine to call `my_fxn` and to pass the return value to `assertEquals`. In that case we're interested in what the function returns, not whether its execution is interrupted by an exception, and we can call `my_fxn` before `assertEquals` executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assertRaises` calls the function, catches the exception, and passes the tests.

You could call it as `assertRaises(ValueError, my_fxn, bad_arg)`, and it would call `my_fxn` with `bad_arg`.

`lambda` creates a callable expression, but doesn't call it. So you could assign the lambda to a name:

```
my_name = lambda: my_fxn(bad_arg)
```

and then pass it to assertRaises (without calling it either):

```
assertRaises(ValueError, my_name)
```

`assertRaises` will call it inside, and fail only if the function doesn't raise an exception. For example:

```
def assertRaises(error_type, function):
    try:
        function()
        assertFail()
    except error_type:
        pass
```